# Object hierarchy

Tags: parent, groups

Say I have a very simple object (e.g. a house) that consist out of the roof and the walls. 
How do I actually model this relationship using Blender? With CTRL+P I can either make roof or the walls the parent of the respective other object. But neither roof nor walls actually, logically, should be the parent but a new object called "house". "House" so to say should consist out of the union of roof and walls, but Blender should still be aware of the separate children objects.

[image][image]

Is this comprehensible?

Comment: If your object "house" has no geometry, it can be an empty. Then parent walls and roof to it.

Comment: Yep, just create an empty object, name it "House" and parent both Walls and Roof to it.